# Getting a datetime variable from a database using dataTableReader

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

So i have a database and i am getting from it it's data by dataTableReader.

I think when you get them from the database you get them as an `object`, not sure, but for sure it's not the variable i set them to be in the database.

so fur I have used only `int` and `varchar` in the database so i have converted them by using `toString()` and `int.parse()`. now  i need to use a datetime variable.

How can i get it from the database as a datetime or convert it to datetime and not as string(using `toString()`)? Thanks for the Help

Comment: 1.in which format you are storing the `Datetime` in database? 2.does it also include time?

Comment: format datetime, it does include time but it's not important so much, i can take it off the time and leave the date only if you have a solution

Comment: check my answer below. is that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do in most cases:

```
var datetime = DateTime.Parse("string");
```

The string being the string saved in the database

Comment: @SonerGönül when a string is stored in a database it stores in usual format right? correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 3):

Try `Convert.ToDateTime(myDataReader[i])` where `i` is the index of your column.

Comment: Thank you very much, but DateTime.parse("String") did it

Answer (score 2):

> How can i get it from the database as a datetime or convert it to
>   datetime and not as string(using toString())?

**Solution 1:** if you are storing the Date value as `DateTime` type then you can directly convert into DateTime using `Convert.ToDateTime()` method

Try This:

```
DataReader dr = new DataReader();
DateTime dt;
while(dr.Read())
{
dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DateColumn"]);
}
```

**Solution 2:** If you are storing the Date in some fixed format like `dd-MM-yyyy`  as `VARCHAR` then you can use `DateTime.ParseExact()` method

Try This:

```
DataReader dr = new DataReader();
DateTime dt;
while(dr.Read())
{
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["DateColumn"].ToString(),"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but DateTime.parse("String") did it

Answer (score 0):

try this `dateTimePicker_dob.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr[i].ToString());`

in here `i` is the index of your DB column and `dateTimePicker_dob` is your dateTimePicker Design(Name)